# How to get int to a SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android

I have a method that collect the year, month and day from a DatePicker and stores them in separate integers.

```
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {                    
    yearD = year;
    monthD = (month + 1);
    dayD = dayOfMonth;
}
```

How can I transform these integers to a SimpleDateFormat with the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd"?

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: You create a `Calendar` object using your day, month, and year. Then you format the `Calendar` object using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I guess that should do the trick:

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar cal = new Calendar().set(year, month, day);

formatter.format(cal);`

Answer (score 2):

First you create a calendar object such as

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0);
```

Now format as per your requirement as below

```
Date date = c.getTime();  
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Though I have not tested the code on IDE but I hope it will give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that should do the trick:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Calendar cal = new Calendar().set(year, month, day); 
formatter.format(cal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is **not strictly an answer**, I would recommend you to jump from the old and error prune Calendar / DatePicker classes,  to the intuitive new **LocalDate** class. If you are interested, let me know and I'll tell you how :)